# Можно ли сделать простое ul li меню стандартным модулем mod_menu в Joomla 3

Tags: html, css, joomla

Приветствую всех

Вопрос заключается в том, имеет ли mod_menu возможность генерировать меню вида ul li? В старых версиях joomla судя по информации в сети можно было выбирать стиль модуля и такой конструкции соответствовал "плоский стиль", а вот как быть в joomla 3 совсем непонятно.

Comment: Даже больше вопрос в том, как выбирать его стиль. Вертикальное, горизонтальное или плоское меню.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "меню вида ul li"? Оно по умолчанию такое и есть. А шаблон, если что-то не устраивает в стандартом вы можете переопределить в своем шаблоне сайта.

Comment: Уже увидел, что действительно по умолчанию такое и есть.Тогда вопрос, каким образов выбирается ориентацию меню? Горизонтальное, вертикальное или список?